# List open Firefox tabs from the command line?

Tags: command-line, firefox, browser-tabs

Is there a way to list the open tabs in Firefox from the command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea would be to access Firefox data from the 'outside'. You might want to look at Stack Overflow question *[How can I get list of open tabs in Firefox via a command-line application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3674633/70482)*.

Comment: Ahhh - the sessionstore.js (JSON) file in your FF profile does seem to contain the appropriate list. Albeit inside a lot of noise. Seems structured enough to parse out though. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Heh - as soon as I get 15 rep, I'll drop back and +1 you :)

Answer (score 12):

The format in latest versions is JSON compressed with LZ4 + a magic header (mozLz40\0).

This small python script will print tabs:
https://gist.github.com/tmonjalo/33c4402b0d35f1233020bf427b5539fa

Comment: To use it in Ubuntu, you need to `sudo apt install python3-lz4`

Comment: the code above works, but one may have another folder under linux, https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data this is a link to find a right one (originaly suggested by mwalkerr)

Answer (score 8):

I recommend using https://github.com/balta2ar/brotab for this purpose:

```
pip install brotab
brotab install
```

Install the web extension as well: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/brotab/

Restart Firefox, and you can run brotab commands such as:

```
brotab list
```

Answer (score 4):

In Linux, you can do it with this (admittedly long) command:

```bash
lz4jsoncat $profile/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4 \
| jq -r '.windows[] | .tabs[] | (.index - 1) as $i | .entries[$i] | .title, .url, ""'
```

This assumes you have set the `$profile` variable to your current Firefox profile with something like

```bash
profile=$HOME/.mozilla/firefox/Your_Profile
```

It needs the [`lz4json`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lz4json) and [`jq`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jq) packages. In Debian or Ubuntu, install them if needed with :

```
sudo apt install lz4json jq
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the mozilla site, no.
[Command Line Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options)

Although you could write a plugin to write tab names to a text file I guess.

Comment: Thanks, I think your answer is the "right" one from a supported standpoint. But, hack > nothing.

Comment: No worries :) happy hacking